# How do I create audiences in Google Analytics 4 using an API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Google Analytics 4 allows new custom audiences to be created:
[image]

I want to do this programmatically through a web API, but I can't see any documentation. Is it possible to create audiences in Google Analytics 4 using an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when added, but...

Web API:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties.audiences/create

.NET client:
https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Analytics.Admin.V1Alpha/latest/api/Google.Analytics.Admin.V1Alpha.AnalyticsAdminService.AnalyticsAdminServiceClient.html#Google_Analytics_Admin_V1Alpha_AnalyticsAdminService_AnalyticsAdminServiceClient_CreateAudience_Google_Analytics_Admin_V1Alpha_CreateAudienceRequest_Grpc_Core_CallOptions_

Comment: Brilliant, thanks.  Yes, it looks like Google have added a bunch of new API's since I raised the question.

Answer (score 1):

Google [have confirmed that "the creation of audiences is not yet supported in Admin API"](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233587531#comment2) and have raised a feature request. They've not given a timeline for implementation but suggested following [the Google Analytics API Notify group for future updates](https://groups.google.com/g/google-analytics-api-notify).

I need to remember that even after this feature is implemented in the GA Admin  grpc API, [it will also need to be supported in the .NET client library that I'm using](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/8498), so there will take some additional time.